# can't get wifi to work on lubuntu 18.04 and Dell Lattitude D610

Tags: networking, dell, broadcom

My wifi card (which works fine under Fedora) is not working. I get the following messages from dmesg:

```
[   38.596450] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[   38.596455] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[   38.596459] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

That site doesn't exist, but a more general search led me to: [linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43](http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43)

This site told me to execute the folowwing command :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 103 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 b43-fwcutter i386 1:019-3 [23.7 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 firmware-b43-installer all 1:019-3 [3950 B]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Fetched 27.7 kB in 0s (64.0 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package b43-fwcutter.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 127592 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../b43-fwcutter_1%3a019-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking b43-fwcutter (1:019-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package firmware-b43-installer.
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-b43-installer_1%3a019-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (1:019-3) ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:019-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:019-3) ...
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation
--2019-11-28 20:01:03--  http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
Resolving www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)... 173.254.30.178
Connecting to www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)|173.254.30.178|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13514651 (13M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’


          broadcom-   0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               
         broadcom-w   0%[                    ] 101.54K   493KB/s               
        broadcom-wl   3%[                    ] 406.98K   981KB/s               
       broadcom-wl-   5%[>                   ] 760.49K  1.20MB/s               
      broadcom-wl-5   8%[>                   ]   1.14M  1.36MB/s               
     broadcom-wl-5.  11%[=>                  ]   1.49M  1.42MB/s               
    broadcom-wl-5.1  14%[=>                  ]   1.82M  1.44MB/s               
   broadcom-wl-5.10  16%[==>                 ]   2.17M  1.47MB/s               
  broadcom-wl-5.100  19%[==>                 ]   2.53M  1.50MB/s               
 broadcom-wl-5.100.  22%[===>                ]   2.90M  1.54MB/s               
broadcom-wl-5.100.1  25%[====>               ]   3.30M  1.57MB/s               
roadcom-wl-5.100.13  28%[====>               ]   3.69M  1.60MB/s               
oadcom-wl-5.100.138  31%[=====>              ]   4.04M  1.59MB/s               
adcom-wl-5.100.138.  33%[=====>              ]   4.33M  1.58MB/s               
dcom-wl-5.100.138.t  36%[======>             ]   4.65M  1.58MB/s               
com-wl-5.100.138.ta  38%[======>             ]   4.96M  1.58MB/s    eta 5s     
om-wl-5.100.138.tar  40%[=======>            ]   5.27M  1.57MB/s    eta 5s     
m-wl-5.100.138.tar.  43%[=======>            ]   5.60M  1.64MB/s    eta 5s     
-wl-5.100.138.tar.b  46%[========>           ]   5.94M  1.65MB/s    eta 5s     
wl-5.100.138.tar.bz  48%[========>           ]   6.28M  1.64MB/s    eta 5s     
l-5.100.138.tar.bz2  51%[=========>          ]   6.62M  1.65MB/s    eta 4s     
-5.100.138.tar.bz2   54%[=========>          ]   6.97M  1.62MB/s    eta 4s     
5.100.138.tar.bz2    56%[==========>         ]   7.32M  1.62MB/s    eta 4s     
.100.138.tar.bz2     59%[==========>         ]   7.68M  1.61MB/s    eta 4s     
100.138.tar.bz2      62%[===========>        ]   8.04M  1.62MB/s    eta 4s     
00.138.tar.bz2       65%[============>       ]   8.41M  1.64MB/s    eta 3s     
0.138.tar.bz2        68%[============>       ]   8.78M  1.61MB/s    eta 3s     
.138.tar.bz2         71%[=============>      ]   9.16M  1.65MB/s    eta 3s     
138.tar.bz2          74%[=============>      ]   9.55M  1.64MB/s    eta 3s     
38.tar.bz2           77%[==============>     ]   9.94M  1.67MB/s    eta 3s     
8.tar.bz2            80%[===============>    ]  10.34M  1.70MB/s    eta 2s     
.tar.bz2             83%[===============>    ]  10.75M  1.72MB/s    eta 2s     
tar.bz2              86%[================>   ]  11.16M  1.73MB/s    eta 2s     
ar.bz2               89%[================>   ]  11.58M  1.78MB/s    eta 2s     
r.bz2                93%[=================>  ]  12.01M  1.78MB/s    eta 2s     
.bz2                 96%[==================> ]  12.44M  1.83MB/s    eta 0s     
bz2                  99%[==================> ]  12.80M  1.81MB/s    eta 0s     
broadcom-wl-5.100.1 100%[===================>]  12.89M  1.83MB/s    in 7.6s    

2019-11-28 20:01:11 (1.70 MB/s) - ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’ saved [13514651/13514651]

Deleting old extracted firmware...
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_ap.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_sta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/README
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_lx_shared
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl.mk
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_default
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_hnd
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_nomimo
This file is recognised as:
  filename   :  wl_apsta.o
  version    :  666.2
  MD5        :  e1b05e268bcdbfef3560c28fc161f30e
Extracting b43/lp0initvals14.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals17.fw
Extracting b43/ucode17_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_lp.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lp2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3bsinitvals21.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode25_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals14.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/n2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode date:     2011-02-23
Extracting b43/n1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/n1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode33_lcn40.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400bsinitvals33.fw
Extracting b43/ucode14.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n16initvals30.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400initvals33.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n18initvals32.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0absinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode26_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3initvals21.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/pcm5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode32_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/n18bsinitvals32.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals17.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals15.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode5.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode11.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals29.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode29_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/ucode30_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n16bsinitvals30.fw
Extracting b43/ucode25_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode27_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/ucode15.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals15.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals29.fw
```

So it looked like this found the file, but when I reboot I get the exact same error message.

I am running off a live USB, is this the problem ?

Any help would be appreciated ! My laptop is too old to update to a later version of Fedora and Lubuntu seems like a good solution for me except for my WiFi problem.

Comment: If you are running off a 'live' USB, all changes are saved only in memory and yes a reboot will cause the system to start again fresh (all changes made in prior sessions gone).  This is a beauty of 'live' systems - you can 'test' things out without impacting anything (reboot and it's gone).  Adding software to an installed system will have it saved for good.

Answer (score 0):

...So I installed to my hard drive, and all is well after following the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WiFiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers.

Thanks !